# RotateY transition not working properly

Tags: javascript, html, css

When i hover once, transition is proper, but on second time, transition becomes wierd, as if the perspective: 800px starts working after transition has taken place.
Please also tell how can i set rotation about an edge except center.
I know about transform-origin but nothing such as transform-axis.

I want that when i hover over the , these images should open like a window.

```js
var left=document.getElementById("left");
var right=document.getElementById("right");
function curtain() {
 left.style.transform="rotateY(70deg)";
 right.style.transform="rotateY(-70deg)";
}
function back() {
 left.style.transform="rotateY(0deg)";
 right.style.transform="rotateY(0deg)";
}
```

```css
#animate{
    width: 400px;
 height: 300px;
 margin: auto;
 position: relative;
 perspective: 800px;
}
img {
 width: 100%;
}
#left {
 position:absolute;
 top: 0;
 right: 50%;
 padding: 0;
 margin: 0;
 width: 50%;
 transition: transform 0.5s;
}
#right {
 position: absolute;
 top: 0;
 right: 0%;
 padding: 0;
 margin: 0;
 width: 50%;
    transition: transform 0.5s;
}
```

```html
<html>
    <head>
     <link href="style/style.css" rel="stylesheet">
 </head>
 <body>
     <div id="animate" onmouseover="curtain()" onmouseout="back()">
      <div id="left"><img src="https://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/commons/thumb/e/e6/Ariyunda.JPG/200px-Ariyunda.JPG"></div>
   <div id="right"><img src="http://www.cs.cornell.edu/courses/cs3110/2009sp/hw/ps4/beach_original.png"></div>
  </div>
  <script src="script/script.js"></script>
 </body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 4):

There seems to be an issue with `perspective` and the `onmouseout`. `back()` (in `onmouseout`) and `curtain()` (in `onmouseover`) are called quite inconsistently. `onmouseout` is called whenever the mouse moves outside the element (`#animate` in this case) or its children (the images). The children are animated - they move - and the `onmouseout` is thereby called multiple times.

I wouldn't recommend `onmouseover` / `onmouseout` for this - instead I would use CSS `:hover`.

That aside, `transform-origin` defines the center of rotation.

```css
#animate:hover #left {
    transform: rotateY(70deg);
}

#animate:hover #right {
    transform: rotateY(-70deg);
}

#animate {
    width: 400px;
    height: 300px;
    margin: auto;
    position: relative;
    perspective: 800px;
}

img {
    width: 100%;
}

#left {
    position: absolute;
    top: 0;
    right: 50%;
    padding: 0;
    margin: 0;
    width: 50%;
    transition: transform 0.5s;
    transform-origin: left;
}

#right {
    position: absolute;
    top: 0;
    right: 0%;
    padding: 0;
    margin: 0;
    width: 50%;
    transition: transform 0.5s;
    transform-origin: right;
}
```

```html
<div id = 'animate'>
    <div id = 'left'><img src = 'https://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/commons/thumb/e/e6/Ariyunda.JPG/200px-Ariyunda.JPG'></div>
    <div id = 'right'><img src = 'http://www.cs.cornell.edu/courses/cs3110/2009sp/hw/ps4/beach_original.png'></div>
</div>
```

Comment: can u pls explain how onmouseout is being called multiple times @fzzle
....and is there anything we can do to call it just once...

Comment: `onmouseout` is called when the mouse is moved out of `#animate`, but also when you move the mouse out of `#left` & `#right` - `onmouseout` is aslo called when the mouse is moved outside its children.  If you're familiar with jQuery, you could use `.mouseenter` and `.mouseleave`. It's quite complex to do it with vanilla JavaScript.

Comment: Your JavaScript solution could work if you change `"rotateY(0deg)"` in `back()` to `""` (an empty string). This wouldn't fix that it's called multiple times, though.

Comment: I made 2 buttons and assigned them animate() and back() onclick.......the 2 buttons are not inside the parent div......this time there should be no problem i guess.....but still same problem. @fzzle

Comment: I know buddy thanx for that but i am concerned that even on creation of buttons, why is the transition still misbehaving. @fzzle

Comment: That's true. It's very strange, indeed.

Answer (score -1):

I don't know the origin of the problem, but it works ok if you are using CSS hover instead of JS hover.

And the transform origin **is** the way to go, it does what your wanted  *transform-axis* would do.

```css
#animate{
    width: 400px;
 height: 300px;
 margin: auto;
 position: relative;
 perspective: 800px;
}
img {
 width: 100%;
}
#left {
 position:absolute;
 top: 0;
 right: 50%;
 padding: 0;
 margin: 0;
 width: 50%;
 transition: transform 0.5s;
    transform: rotateY(0deg);
  transform-origin: left center;
}
#right {
 position: absolute;
 top: 0;
 right: 0%;
 padding: 0;
 margin: 0;
 width: 50%;
    transition: transform 0.5s;
    transform: rotateY(0deg);
  transform-origin: right center;
}

#animate:hover #left {
    transform: rotateY(70deg);
  
}
#animate:hover #right {
    transform: rotateY(-70deg);
  
}
```

```html
<div id="animate" onmouseover="curtain()" onmouseout="back()">
      <div id="left"><img src="https://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/commons/thumb/e/e6/Ariyunda.JPG/200px-Ariyunda.JPG"></div>
   <div id="right"><img src="http://www.cs.cornell.edu/courses/cs3110/2009sp/hw/ps4/beach_original.png"></div>
  </div>
```